# PHP - Namespace isn't working properly

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, runtime-error

I am using xampp on windows 7 with php 5.6.24. I have problem with php Namespace.

My project direcotry look like this :

```
-project
 + config
 - Framework
   + database
   + Expection
   test.php
 + src
 index.php
```

I have php file inside Framework/test.php and it contains the following code :

```
<?php
namespace Framework\Test;
echo " i  Am in test.php class";
class Test{
    public function __construct(){
        echo "I m from test classs ";
    }

    public function test_method(){
        echo " No";
    }
}
```

In my root directory i have index.php, composer.json

My composer.json has autoload object

```
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Framework\\": "Framework/"
    },
    "files": [
        "src/Helpers/ArrayHelpers.php"
    ]
  },
```

In my index.php, i have following code :

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Framework\Test;
$n      = new Test;
print_r($n);
```

When i run `index.php` file on browser i get the responce :

> i  Am in test.php class;
>
> Fatal error:  Class 'Framework\Test' not found in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\project\index.php on line 12

I don't know what i am doing wrong ? Is my namespace is wrong ? But i am getting echo from that file how ? why ? whats going wrong ? is my composer file wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Class `Test` in `namespace Framework\Test` has FQCN `Framework\Test\Test`

Comment: @u_mulder no it still doesn't work

Comment: Try `$n = new Test\Test();` or namespacing the alias `use Framework\Test as Fw; $n = new Fw\Test();` - makes it a little more obvious.

Comment: no it still doesnt work. When i use use `Framework\Test;

$n   = new Test();` i think the file is loading( because it shows me echo output from that file) but it give me class not found error. I am understanding why ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace of the class `Test` is simply `Framework`, (because it is located in the Framework folder also) so try to change the <kbd>Test.php</kbd> as follow:

```
<?php
namespace Framework;
echo " i  Am in test.php class";
class Test{
    public function __construct(){
        echo "I m from test classs ";
    }

    public function test_method(){
        echo " No";
    }
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: hi @ManpreetSingh in a class file definition, the `namespace` should reflect the folder organisation (so simply don't specify also the name of the class), when you using a class, you should describe with an `use` statement the full class name definition, hope this clarify